# Decoding timestamp number in "change in schema version between compile time and run time"

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

I am trying to track down a "who/why" for the error

```
<...> reported a change in schema version between compile time ("185302088475260") 
and run time ("185448117384521") for table <...>
```

I am aware of the resolution(s) (recompile the SPROC, or for one of our others that takes ~2 hours, don't touch schema in the linked server until it is complete), however the schema for the specific tables shouldn't be changing. To assist in tracking down who/where/why I would like to decode those compile/run time numbers into some form of datetime or something such that I can narrow down the time frame I need to investigate.

I am having difficulty in finding exactly what those numbers represent, they appear not to be unix timestamps (too many digits), nor .net Ticks, nor a win32 epoch (giving me some year in 1601? Although the "time" part might be right?).